# Java NullPointerException from Point2D.setLocation()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, point

I keep getting a NullPointerException when I try to use the setLocation() method on a Point2D object. I have 6 or 7 Point2D objects in my code and it only throws the exception for this one. Here's the code snippet:

import java.awt.geom.*;

```
public class Box 
{
    private Point2D coord;
    private int height;
    private int width;

    public Box()
    {
        coord.setLocation(0,0);
        height = 40;
        width = 200;
    }
```

...

and the object is created here:

```
public MainGUI()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    view = new ViewPanel();
    controls = new ControlPanel();

    ballAction = new Ball();
    boxAction = new Box();
    springAction = new Spring();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How is your object created in MainGUI? You need to call MainGUI before it is created and your constructor will always be called first so how do you expect it to be created?

Answer (score 4):

Add this:

```
coord = new Point2D();// you may need to pass some parameters to the constructor of the Point2D according to it's definition
```

before trying to use it. (You try to access this object before initializing it)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize coord with :

```
coord = Point2D.Float();
```

or

```
coord = Point2D.Double();
```

depending on x, y datatype.